# How to get the key value pairs in numpy.ndarray? (Gensim Word2vec)

Tags: python, performance, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to get the keys as well as the vectors in the vector `model.syn0` which gives vectors by `model.syn0["word"]` which gives an n-dim vector. Is there a better way to create a list of all the words in the model in the same order as the the vectors of `syn0` than this? I have 350000 words and this would take too long.

```
from gensim.models import word2vec as wv
model = wv.Word2Vec.load('model')
lab=[]
for i in model.syn0:
    lab.append(model.similar_by_vector(i)[0])

print(type(model.syn0))
    <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the direction of [Gordon Mohr](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gensim/$20List$20of$20words$20in$20the$20vocabulary$20(syn0$20word$20list)$20%7Csort:relevance/gensim/qkEZ-MFf-NI/jBHqH14pBwAJ), I found that the key value pairs are stored in `model.index2word`.

So the key-value pairs list can easily be obtained using:

```
lab=model.index2word
```